# Pyathena Schema does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, pyathena

I need to process some data of a certain flow that I have in a specific folder in a bucket `S3`. I want to do this in `Python`. After searching for a while I found the library `PyAthena` which exactly what I was looking for!

I installed the version `1.8.0` of `PyAthena`.

For your information, I have my `S3` bucket in the region of `Paris eu-west-3` and my `Athena` database in the region of `Francfort eu-central-1`.

I used the following code that I found in the documentation [PyAthena Doc](https://pypi.org/project/PyAthena/):

```
from pyathena import connect

cursor = connect(aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
             aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
             s3_staging_dir='s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/',
             region_name='us-west-2').cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM one_row")
print(cursor.description)
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

I was at first not sure about which `region_name` to use, if it should be the one of `Paris` where the `S3` bucket is, or the one of `Francfort` where the `Athena` database is!!

I tried both and following the error messages I got, I ended up using the one of my `S3` bucket!
However I kept getting errors of permissions about `Glue`, something like:

```
pyathena.error.OperationalError: Insufficient permissions to execute the query.  Error retrieving table : master in database : default due to : User: arn:aws:iam::<my-account-client-ID>:user/s3-test is not authorized to perform: glue:GetTable on resource: arn:aws:glue:eu-west-3:<my-account-client-ID>:catalog
```

So I added the following strategy in the `IAM`:

```
        {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "athena:StartQueryExecution",
            "athena:GetQueryResultsStream",
            "athena:GetQueryResults",
            "athena:DeleteNamedQuery",
            "athena:GetNamedQuery",
            "athena:*",
            "athena:ListQueryExecutions",
            "athena:ListNamedQueries",
            "athena:CreateNamedQuery",
            "athena:StopQueryExecution",
            "athena:GetQueryExecution",
            "athena:BatchGetNamedQuery",
            "athena:BatchGetQueryExecution"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "glue:GetTable",
            "glue:GetTables",
            "glue:GetDatabase"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:glue:eu-west-3:<my-account-client-ID>:catalog",
            "arn:aws:glue:eu-west-3:<my-account-client-ID>:database/*",
            "arn:aws:glue:eu-west-3:<my-account-client-ID>:table/*/*"
        ]
    }
```

Now I have this error message:

```
    cursor.execute("select * from master")
    File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyathena/util.py", line 28, in _wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyathena/cursor.py", line 57, in execute
raise OperationalError(query_execution.state_change_reason)
    pyathena.error.OperationalError: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:15: Schema default does not exist
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the select statement: if you do not indicate it you will use the database *default* and if you do not have such database in your environment it will fail. You should indicate your database and table:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <YOUR_DATABASE>.<YOUR_TABLE>")
```

Or you could also specify the database name (or schema name) with a parameter in the cursor function:

```
cursor = connect(aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
             aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
             s3_staging_dir='s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/',
             region_name='us-west-2').cursor(schema_name=<YOUR_DATABASE>)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <YOUR_TABLE>")
```

If you do one of that you should not get the same error anymore.